# makefile multiple source file compilation rule in one step

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have a directory structure as below:
    Makefile
    src/
        file1.cpp file2.cpp
    inc/
       file1.h file2.h
Now I wanted to write a make rule to create a 'objs' directory and put all my objects(.o files) in 'objs' and then build a library out of it. I wanted to do this in one shot rather than writing one rule for each .cpp file.
This is what I tried:

```
SRC_DIR:= src/
INC_DIR:=inc/

SRC_PATH:=$(foreach var, $(SRC_DIR), $(wildcard $(var)*.cpp))
OBJ_PATH:=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRC_PATH))
OBJ_PATH:=$(notdir $(OBJ_PATH))
OBJ_DIR:=./objs
OBJ_PATH:=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(OBJ_PATH))

TARGET:=libcommon.a

all:$(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ_PATH)
    ar -rcs $(TARGET) $(OBJ_PATH)
$(OBJ_PATH): $(SRC_PATH)    
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CXX) -o $(OBJ_PATH) -c $(SRC_PATH) -I$(INC_DIR)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
[root@localhost common]# make
mkdir -p ./objs
g++   -o ./objs/file1.o ./objs/file2.o -c  src/file1.cpp src/file2.cpp -Iinc/
g++: ./objs/file1.o: No such file or directory
g++: cannot specify -o with -c or -S with multiple files
```

I did a lot of search in this topic. Didn't get any help. Please point me the mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors in you code: you use lists in place of $@

I like solution with src and header in auto search in subdirectories.

```
OBJ_DIR:=./objs

SOURCES:=$(wildcard */*.cpp *.cpp)
OBJECTS:= $(notdir $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))
OBJECTS_LOCAL:=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
LOCAL_PATHS_HEADERS:=$(sort $(dir $(wildcard *.h */*.h)))

OBJ_PATH:=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(OBJECTS))

TARGET:=libcommon.a

all:$(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS_LOCAL)
        ar -rcs $@ $(OBJ_PATH)

$(OBJECTS_LOCAL):
        mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
        $(CC) -c $(@:.o=.cpp) -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$(notdir $@) $(addprefix -I,$(LOCAL_PATHS_HEADERS))
```

--add

Solution wo recompiled, but it's need manual control SRC_DIR

```
OBJ_DIR:=obj
SRC_DIR:=src

SOURCES:=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS_PATH:=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(notdir $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)))
LOCAL_PATHS_HEADERS:=$(sort $(dir $(wildcard *.h */*.h)))

TARGET:=libcommon.a

all:$(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS_PATH)
        ar -rcs $@ $^

$(OBJECTS_PATH): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
        mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
        $(CC) -o  $@ -c $< $(addprefix -I,$(LOCAL_PATHS_HEADERS))
```

Comment: The solution works fine. Thanks for the help. But one problem here is that every time the make is executed the source is recompiled. How can we rectify this?. I mean .c file should only be compiled if it has a time stamp change.

Comment: @deadbeef i have other solution, but it's have some limitation to auto

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. This works as per my expectations. But I didn't understand this line: ` $(OBJECTS_PATH): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp`. Can you just explain what this statement is doing?

Comment: @deadbeef Manual explain it's better than I can. You need read [About targets : target-pattern: prereq-patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html) and [About %](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules)