# Makefile: Compile all files into one folder without subfolder

Tags: makefile

There is my directory structure:

```
                            Project
                              |
              +---------------+----------------+
              |               |                |
           Sources/         Temp/         Makefile
              |               |                
         +----+----+         *.o      
         |         |                         
       Test/    *.cpp
         |
        *.cpp
```

I'm trying to compile every `.cpp` into my `Temp` directory without subfolder.

There is my `Makefile`:

```
CC = g++
WARNING = -w
OPTIMIZATION = -O0
ARGUMENTS = -g

INCLUDES = -I Includes -I Sources
LIBS = -L

OBJDIR = Temp

SRC = $(wildcard Sources/*.cpp) $(wildcard Sources/*/*.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(SRC:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)


App: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^


$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(WARNING) $(OPTIMIZATION) $(ARGUMENTS) -c $< -o $@
```

When I run it, it always try to create a subfolder into my `Temp`:

```
g++ -w -O0 -g -c Sources/Main.cpp -o Temp/Sources/Main.o
```

I think that I need to use `OBJECTS = $(SRC:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/$(%F).o)`, but I'm new with the `Makefile` and I don't know how I can make this work...

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finaly find a way to do it. I found the solution in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419322/makefile-multiple-source-file-compilation-rule-in-one-step?rq=1).

The solution is `$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(notdir $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)))`. Look like I have to use the `notdir` function instead of the `$(%F)` variable.